# What is the difference between the Maven MySQL connector and the official MySQL connector JAR file?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, mysql-connector

Recently I was working with JDBC, and all code which uses JDBC were working perfectly.

After some time I started using JDBC again to refresh all concepts. The problem is, when I wrote my new program at that time, it gave me ClassNotFoundException. Everything in my code was perfect. I also added the external JAR file of the MySQL connector. The exception was **ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**.

I tried different IDEs to run that code, but it gave me the same error. But then I tried to import [this MySQL connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.11) from the Maven repository and all the exceptions were cleared and executed perfectly.

Previously I was using [this MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Also both connectors versions were the same which was 8.0.11. I have really less amount of knowledge of Maven.

Why did the MySQL connector JAR file from Maven work perfectly and the other didn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've said, it sounds like your manually-imported JAR file didn't import for one reason or another. The Maven import was successful and everything clicked.

The other thing that's possible is that you're using a different version of the MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: Both connectors version was same which was 8.0.11.I also tried mysql-connector-java-5.1.46 but the result was same.But connector 8.0.11 from maven worked.

Comment: So you didn't deploy  the other one properly. The error message is quite clear. The class was not found. That's not a problem with that JAR file: this is a problem caused by the *absence* of that JAR file.

Comment: @EJP But the jar file was added succesfully and issue was still there.

Comment: @Under_stand you might have added the jar but its not in your classpath.

Comment: I have figured out the solution.I was importing zip file which contains jar file and other stuff.When i imported the jar file only which is inside of that zip all the things worked.In future should i need to import that specific jar file only rather than zip file which contains that jar file?

Comment: @Under_Stand that is correct, Java will not extract zip files looking for libraries. If my answer helped you I'd appreciate if you could select my answer as correct.